# Couchdb replication based on sequence number

Tags: git, couchdb

**Problem**: 
I don't have a whole lot of documents but each document has gone through a lot of revisions and therefore there is much history and the update_seq number is huge.

When I try to replicate this to my local db for the first time it takes a lot of time. I am doing a one time replication.

**Question**: 
Is there a way to do a one time replication based on seq numbers ? Something like git clone --depth=x .

I only want to copy the latest version (leaf versions) of the document when I do this replication.

How do I go about this ? Please advise. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB replicates only leaf revisions, so (unless the history of your document is non-linear) it should fetch only the latest revision. So this is in fact somewhat equivalent to

```
git clone --depth=1 --no-single-branch
```

Please see [this diagram](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-full-sync/blob/master/doc/chart1.png) for visual explanation of this concept.

There is no possibility of limiting the depth of the replication to single 'branch' (which is the default `git` behaviour), because it breaks the CouchDB conflict resolution mechanism.

If you experience slow replication for fresh copies, then you may try one of the following:

- Check how many leaf revisions you have for your document: `curl http://server/database/document?conflicts=true`. If you have many, consider resolving the conflicts by removing the unneeded leaves.
- Perform compaction on the source database -- it should rebuild the B-trees for the database and make fetching revision tree faster during the replication.